# Design decisions concerning migrating medium sized content site to drupal 7

Tags: import, migration, drupal-7

We are in the process of moving a legacy asp.net 2.0 content site to drupal 7.  We are a pretty traditional entertainment content site with about 8 years worth of content (5gb database) which consists of mostly custom articles like news, movie reviews etc..

Another big chunk of our data that we import every day includes image galleries of celebrities, syndicated news and most importantly movie, tv and celebrity data from All music guide (AMG).  We have seen first hand what happens to drupal applications that insist on circumventing the drupal API for importing and working with data and understand the huge performance nightmare that can become but our main concern is what to do with importing so much domain specific movie, tv and celebrity data and then having to access it afterwards?

My question is would it be better to create our content types to match our movie, tv and celebrity data schema (and all the relationships within those entities) and just use the drupal API for initial import and daily deltas or would it make more sense to keep the domain data in a traditional domain specific schema and write drupal modules to access that data?

Comment: Define what you mean by "better".  Otherwise this seems to be a good question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a big schema with lots of fields it's probably a better idea to use the [Entity API](http://www.istos.it/blog/drupal/drupal-entities-part-1-moving-beyond-nodes) Drupal 7 provides instead of using content types. That way you'd be able to use your domain specific schema which should speed things up. I have been using it for a while on a lot of data and it sounds exactly like what you need.